# Getting date from input field inserted in mySQL - using classic asp

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

Here's my issue:

I have a webpage where people submit various cases. These cases contain a date (Date received). In mySQL that column is DateTime. This part works fine - date is received by the database.

However - I've created a different table where I'll store all communication going on regarding that exact case. In this table I'd like to store the originally inserted date of the case. Currently I extract that date using a query in classic asp (yes, I'm that old) and then put that into a form as a hidden type. It displays fine on the page where relevant information regarding the case is being changed, but when passed on to the server using request.form to obtain the original date MySQL only inserts 000-00-00 00:00:00. Any thoughts?

Code seen below (it's awful - I know):

```
strSQL = "Insert into idFejlmelding (cid, Navn, Udstyr, Beskrivelse," _
    & " Datomodtaget, DatoAfsluttet, Status, Bemaerkninger, Email, Sagsnr)" _
    & " values('" & Request.Form("cid") & "','" & Request.Form("navn1") & "','" _
    & Request.Form("udstyr1") & "','" & Request.Form("beskrivelse1") & "','" _
    & Request.Form("Datomodtaget1") & "','" & d & "','" & Request.Form("status1") & "','" _
    & Request.Form("bemaerkninger1") & "','" & Request.Form("email1") & "','" _
    & Request.Form("Sagsnr") & "')"
```

Request.Form(Datomodtaget1) is the culprit. It displays as 11-08-2015 09:00:12

Comment: Show how you're assigning to the `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: What Bond said: we need to see what's in your form. For example, if the hidden field in question is `<input type='hidden' name='Datomodtaget' value='<%=Datomodtaget1%>'>`, but you're doing `Request.Form("Datomodtaget1")`, then that would result in exactly the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Can you post the result of `Response.Write strSQL` so we can see the generated SQL?